# Active Shape Model Build my own model

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to implement **Active shape Model** algorithm. I tried to **detect eyes corners** so that I searched how to make my own model using the MUCT database. I have followed this link:`https://code.google.com/p/asmlib-opencv/source/browse/trunk/data/muct/README.txt`. 
when I download the lib I don't get the prepare.sh file so that I just copied in my directory but when running ./prepare.sh I get errors: `no such file or directoryownload http://muct.googlecode.com/files/muct-landmarks-v1.tar.gz%0D Resolving muct.googlecode.com (muct.googlecode.com)... 173.194.70.82, 2a00:1450:4001:c02::52 Connecting to muct.googlecode.com (muct.googlecode.com)|173.194.70.82|:80... connected.HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 2013-06-06 09:47:14 ERROR 404: Not Found.`
I can't figure out the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think, You should look here:
[Code for the book "Mastering OpenCV with Practical Computer Vision Projects" by Packt Publishing 2012](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code)
There are several interesting projects, and statistical models used in
Chapter6_NonRigidFaceTracking project (using MUCT face database).

[You can download MUCT here.](http://code.google.com/p/muct/downloads/list)